# Facebook SDK 4.0: Asking publish_actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using **FBSDKLoginButton** for logging in through **Facebook** in my App. Well I define the **readPermissions** as;

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public_profile", @"email",nil];
self.loginFbBtn.readPermissions = permissions;
```

The above goes all well. But now if I need to ask permissions for a post to my timeline and want to have access to "**publish_actions**" permissions, is there a way to ask these without actually provoking **FBSDKLoginManager**, because that is the only way given in [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions):

```
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
  // TODO: publish content.
} else {
  FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    //TODO: process error or result.
  }];
}
```

Apparently this is the only way you can invoke "**publish_actions**" for your app. I want to use it without the **FBSDKLoginManager**. Please help, I need to get this rolling.

**SO THIS IS THE UPDATE:**

By the help of *Wizkid* and *MingLi* I ended up implementing it via **FBSDKLoginManager** and the following code segments are for Facebook Login via a custom button and its `@selector(facebookLogin)`, and then sharing permissions invoked when sharing is required via method `getSharingPermissions` :

```
-(void) facebookLogin
{
    @try
    {
        self.loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [self.loginManager setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb];
        [self.loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result,NSError *error)
        {
            if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
            {
                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                 {
                     if (!error)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                         NSDictionary *userDict = (NSDictionary*)result;
                     }
                 }];
            }}];
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"Exception %@", exception);
}
```

Get Sharing Permissions:

```
-(void)getSharePermissions
{
    if (![[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"])
    {
        [self.loginManager setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb];
        [self.loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
        {
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"])
            {

            }}];
    }
}
```

So the error is I am getting the Login page again and is asking User Credentials again when `getSharingPermissions` is called. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you not want to use FBSDKLoginManager?

Comment: Because it tries to switch Views, whereas my App specifically is designed to entertain different users, and therefore my self.loginFbBtn is:  
self.loginButton.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb; 
that is it uses the webview within the app. You get my drift?

Comment: Having more than one person use Facebook login on the same device is a bad idea. You have have problems in the future

Comment: Ahan? Well that is the requirement, sadly! And FBLoginView was doing it comfortably for me but f8 want to wreck havoc on programmers over and over again! :P

Comment: You can set the same loginBehavior on FBSDKLoginManager.

Comment: @MingLi : I tried that, the loginBehavior appears and then instantly goes away! :/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean that the webview pops up, but then disappears?

Comment: Yes, sir! Exactly! Thats what happens.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. I'm using the Scrumptious sample app, and just changed the _postOpenGraphAction method in the SCShareUtility.m to specify FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb for the loginBehavior. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Im not getting any errors though if I try to do it with FBSDKLoginManager and with FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb, FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult is nil and it asks for login details again and then asks publish_actions. Can it not take the user credentials again and how do I make sure the FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult is not nil because I need that data/response to take further actions.

Comment: I suspect it's something in your code. Can you try my suggestions and look at the Scrumptious sample? I made the changes and requesting publish permissions in a webview worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Ok so I am going to do that. Lets see how that'll go for me. I did try the ShareIt sample but it was using the FBSDKLoginButton. Anyhow, I'll pursue this line of thought now. Will get back to you in 10mins

Comment: @MingLi: So guess what? Still asking User Credentials again. As in the Scrumptious app is working fine, but everytime i call loginWithPublishPermissions, I get the login asking UserCredentials again and when entered, then the view is shifted to publish_actions page. Arrghh! This is frustrating! Will sleep on it a bit.

Comment: If you already have an access token, it should not ask for log in credentials again.

Comment: Yeah? So I updated the code, any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: @cookiemonsta do you have any progress on this one? I'm having kinda the same problem.

Comment: @kasradzenika Naah man! I however went back to the Native App for confirmation or for that matter, to the browser. What I have observed though is if you use browser or native app, the User Credentials are not asked for again, even if you use FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb for publish_actions, but if you use FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb for initial permissions and again use FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb for publish_actions permissions, it asks the User Credentials again. F8 might be flying high with its new wave, but man, their codes are broken and they won't admit it :/

Comment: @cookiemonsta absolutely agree.